# Variable doesn't want to be defined?

Tags: python, list, variables, python-3.x, global-variables

I have a slight problem where a variable doesn't seem to be properly defined as a variable. When I try to `print` the values of the variable `WordLetters`, it doesn't return anything. When I try to `print` the length of the variable, it returns `0`.

Initially I had a `NameError` in terms of the `WordLetters` variable, then I defined outside the `try:` function, and now it returns no value. Could it be that `try:` has its own scope? And if so, how would I append values to the `WordLetters` list?

```
RandomWord = random.choice(Words)
try:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3], RandomWord[4], RandomWord[5], RandomWord[6], RandomWord[7], RandomWord[8], RandomWord[9]]
except(IndexError):
  pass

print("Word: " + "".join(WordLetters))
print("The word is " + str(len(WordLetters)) +  " letters long.")
```

Comment: You are *silently* ignoring `IndexError` exceptions with `RandomWord`. Please remove the `try...except` and you'll know why `WordLetters` is not set. You have randomly picked a `RandomWord` with fewer than 10 elements.

Comment: Don't you just want `WordLetters = list(RandomWord)`?

Comment: this will only work if `RandoWord` is exactly 10 letters long. you can always find the `len()` of a string.

Comment: Oh, it wants to be defined, you're just not allowing it. It seems to be false that all words in `Words` have at least 10 letters. @Buzz, not exactly 10 but at least 10 chars long.

Comment: @anand-s-kumar it's a simple list of strings

Comment: @martijn-pieters I see

Comment: @BrianO even if the word is more than 10 letters the code is only looking at the first 10 letters. `len(WordLetters)` will always return 10

Comment: What a lengthy code. You can just use RandomWord[:10] :)

Comment: I just thought if I ignored the IndexError, the list would just append what exists, so if the word was 3 letters long, the list would be 3 items long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are silently ignoring index errors by using `except IndexError: pass`. If any of your randomly picked words are shorter than 10 characters, you'll get an exception and `WordLetters` will not be set.

Either set a *default* when that happens, or avoid indexing individual characters altogether; you could just use the `list()` function to create a list with all the individual characters of the word:

```
WordLetters = list(RandomWord)
```

without having to know up-front how many characters there are in the word.

Note that unless you plan to *mutate* the list (change individual elements or add or delete elements from the list) you don't need to turn your string into a list of individual characters. You can always loop over a word or get the length; `len(RandomWord)` works, and so does `for character in RandomWord: print(character)`.

Answer (score -2):

Ignoring IndexError doesn't help.

My solution is to check each word's length, like so:

```
if len(RandomWord) == 2:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1]]
elif len(RandomWord) == 3:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2]]
elif len(RandomWord) == 4:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3]]
elif len(RandomWord) == 5:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3], RandomWord[4]]
elif len(RandomWord) == 6:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3], RandomWord[4], RandomWord[5]]
elif len(RandomWord) == 7:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3], RandomWord[4], RandomWord[5], RandomWord[6]]
else:
  WordLetters = [RandomWord[0], RandomWord[1], RandomWord[2], RandomWord[3], RandomWord[4], RandomWord[5], RandomWord[6], RandomWord[7]]
```

Somewhat lengthy, but it works.

Comment: what if the word is more than 8 letters?

Comment: Or you can just use `WordLetters = list(RandomWord)`, no need to index each individual character.

Comment: @buzz my list doesn't include any words with more than 8 letters.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
aword = 'hello world'
randomWord = []
for i in range(len(aword)):
    randomWord.append(random.choice(aword))

print ''.join(randomWord)
print len(randomWord)
```